# Woocommerce additional registration field validation not working

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, woocommerce, registration

I've followed the tutorial for adding an additional field to registration exactly, but I can't get it to validate. It doesn't need to save, it just needs to be a one-time question to confirm the user is doing the right thing.

I've added the below into functions.php but it's not working... can anyone see why please?

```
function wooc_extra_register_fields() {
?>
<?php if (($_GET['register'] == 'instructor')) : ?>
<p class="form-row form-row-wide">
<label for="reg_instructor"><?php _e( 'Please confirm you\'re trying to register as an instructor', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="instructor" id="reg_instructor" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['instructor'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST['instructor'] ); ?>" />
</p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
}


add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start', 'wooc_extra_register_fields' );
function wooc_validate_extra_register_fields( $username, $email, $validation_errors ) {
if ( isset( $_POST['instructor'] ) && empty( $_POST['instructor'] ) ) {
$validation_errors->add( 'instructor_error', __( 'You must be an instructor!', 'woocommerce' ) );
}
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_post', 'wooc_validate_extra_register_fields', 10, 3 );


add_action('user_profile_update_errors','instructor_validation',10,1);
function instructor_validation($args)
{
if ( isset( $_POST['instructor'] ) && empty( $_POST['instructor'] ) ) {
$args->add( 'instructor_error', __( 'You must be an instructor!', 'woocommerce' ),'');
}
}


function wooc_save_extra_register_fields( $customer_id ) {
if ( isset( $_POST['instructor'] ) ) {
update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'instructor', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['instructor'] ) );
}
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'wooc_save_extra_register_fields' );
```

Any help, much appreciated...

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completely untested, because I can't check it right now. But it seems like you have no value for the checkbox. Then you are validating `if ( isset( $_POST['instructor'] ) && empty( $_POST['instructor'] ) )` but if a checkbox is set, then it is never `empty`, so you're condition would never be met. Lastly you don't need to `sanitize_text_field()` since it isn't a text field.

Instead, I've set the checkbox value to `1` and test if the posted value equals 1. WooCommerce actually uses a lot of `yes` versus `no` for boolean checkboxes and that might even be easier so you can try that if you need to. But for just testing if the box is checked and equal to something specific it almost doesn't matter.

```
function wooc_extra_register_fields() { ?>
    <?php if ( isset($_GET['register']) && ($_GET['register'] == 'instructor')) : ?>
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
    <label for="reg_instructor"><?php _e( 'Please confirm you\'re trying to register as an instructor', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="instructor" id="reg_instructor" value="1" <?php checked ( isset($_POST['instructor']) && 1 == $_POST['instructor'], true ); ?>/>
    </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start', 'wooc_extra_register_fields' );


function wooc_validate_extra_register_fields( $username, $email, $validation_errors ) {
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['instructor'] ) || 1 != $_POST['instructor'] ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'instructor_error', __( 'You must be an instructor!', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_post', 'wooc_validate_extra_register_fields', 10, 3 );



function instructor_validation($args){
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['instructor'] ) || 1 != $_POST['instructor'] ) {
        $args->add( 'instructor_error', __( 'You must be an instructor!', 'woocommerce' ),'');
    }
}
add_action('user_profile_update_errors','instructor_validation',10,1);


function wooc_save_extra_register_fields( $customer_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['instructor'] ) && 1 == $_POST['instructor'] ) {
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'instructor', 1 );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'wooc_save_extra_register_fields' );
```

PS- my code might have adverse effects on registrants who are *not* instructors, should you may need to elaborate on the conditional logic for the validation, probably checking again for the `$_GET['register']` variable.

**EDIT**

Here's my best guess at how to add the user meta to the WooCommerce fields. However, there's no control over what the value displays, so 1. you could either adjust how you save the `instructor` meta... save it as 'yes' or 'instructor' or something. OR, add your own [custom user meta section](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/4029/6477)

```
function wooc_show_customer_meta_fields( $fields ){
    $fields['instructor'] = array(
                'title' => __( 'Instructors', 'your-plugin' ),
                'fields' => array(
                    'instructor' => array(
                        'label'       => __( 'Instructor Status', 'your-plugin' ),
                        'description' => ''
                    )
                );
    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_customer_meta_fields', 'wooc_show_customer_meta_fields' );
```

Comment: Hi, that works great! Thanks for that... only slight error was a double && &&, but other than that it was bang on, so thanks for your help!

Comment: One other thing that is weird with the validation is that one error pops up at a time - it doesn't show all errors at once... is that something that woocommerce just does, or is it to do with the functions above?

Comment: annoyingly, it also doesn't save the additional check box upon submission of the form?

Comment: I *think* the one error at a time is just how WooCommerce behaves. As soon as it gets an error, it will return a `false` to the validating function and quit early. At least that's how it works on add to cart validation so I assume it would be similar here.

Comment: I'm not sure why it it wouldn't save the user meta. I'd try to `error_log(json_encode($_POST))` in the `wooc_save_extra_register_fields()` function as long as you have [`WP_DEBUG_LOG`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) enabled. I'd also try ` error_log(get_user_meta($user_id));` on the new user's ID to be extra sure that it isn't saving instead of you not retrieving it properly. I've had that happen to me plenty if times.

Comment: Hi, thanks I'll give that a try - it's saving my other additional fields (first name / last name etc)... maybe it's just not showing in the Users admin page - that's the only place I'm looking! How would you suggest retrieving it? Thanks again!

Comment: Well it won't automatically show in the admin. You have to add it. [This answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/4029/6477) might help with that. Or you can filter it into WooCommerce's list of user fields via [`woocommerce_customer_meta_fields`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/5893875b0c03dda7b2d448d1a904ccfad3cdae3f/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-profile.php#L39). I'll add my best guess for filtering the latter option.